# Cannot console.log fetch results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to do an API call using fetch().

I'm aware that fetch() returns a Promise and should be handled using `.then` or `await`. The same for the `result.json()` Followed this tutorial http://www.reactnativeexpress.com/networking, I arrived with `fetchRoute()`function. The `console.log(route)` inside the function is never called.

I tried to return `console.log(fetchRoute(this.state.userLocation, text))`, but it was still returning a Promise.

I read another quesiton here on Stack Overflow (sorry, can't find the link anymore), and they said to try something like this:

`getRouteHandler = (text) => {
    fetchRoute(this.state.userLocation, text).then(json => console.log(json));`

Still, I couldn't log the fetch results. Anyone knows what could be going wrong? Here is the relevant code:

```
const fetchRoute = async (ori, dest) => {
  let origin = ori.latitude+','+ori.longitude; 
  let destination = encodeURIComponent(dest); 
  const key = "MyAPIKey";
  const URL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=${origin}&destination=${destination}&key=${key}`;

  try{
    const response = await fetch(URL)
    const route = await response.json()
    console.log(route)
    return route
  }catch(e){
    return e
  }
}

export default class App extends Component{

 state = {
    userLocation: null,
    route: [],
  }

  getRouteHandler = (text) => {
    fetchRoute(this.state.userLocation, text).then(json => console.log(json));
}
```

Comment: The `.then` is the way to go. `Still, I couldn't log the fetch results` What does it log there instead? (Are you sure the request is proper? Check network tab, maybe?)

Comment: There's no result at all. It doesn't print anything on the console for some reason. I also tried to put random log to see if it was entering there, such as the code below. Still no results.

 `    const response = await fetch(URL)
    const route = await response.json()
    console.log("Random string to check if entered ")`

Comment: Like I said, check your network tab - it might be that the request isn't getting through, rather than an issue with your code. You could also check `response.ok` before trying to `await` the `.json()`.

Comment: Write `debugger;` before calling `fetchRoute` and run the code with the inspector. You'll see the code running line by line. I ran your code with stub API and it works for the async/await part, in my humble opinion `getRouteHandler ` is not being called.

Comment: Is there an exception? If so, `console.log(route)` will not triggered. And `console.log(json)` will output the exception.

Comment: @CertainPerformance 
Indeed, I couldn't see the request into the network tab. Do you know what could be cause for this?

Comment: @cnexans
I tried using the debugger, as you suggested. I could see the code running through the getRouteHandler, calling fetchRoute and some stuff happening at fetch.js

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you're fetching large amounts of data it will take awhile for it to log. For example, in a past project the api I was fetching from had close to 5 million records. It took a few minutes to see anything in the console.

Comment: Another side note; I noticed when adding text comments it didn't work. Example: `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` vs `console.log(JSON.stringify("test data", data));`